# Adding a group of check box values into an array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can I add checkbox values into an array using jQuery? because this doesn't seem to work:

```
var fields2 = $("#tblMondayTimes input: checked").serializeArray();                     
var DansArray = new Array();
var BookableTimes = $.each(fields2, function(i, field){
DansArray[field.value];
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var DansArray = [];
$("#tblMondayTimes input:checked").each(function() {
    DansArray.push($(this).val()); //push each val into the array
});
```